# how to show an iterative equation converges to a fixed point

Tags: convergence-divergence, fixed-point-theorems

let's consider the equation $y'(t) = 16-y^2 = f(t,y)$

for all  $t\in [0,1]$  and  $y(0) = 0$.

How small should the step size $h$ be to ensure the following equation converge for all $i \geq 0 $. This can be achieved by doing numerically using fix point iteration of the Crank-Nicolson scheme given by:

$y_{i+1}^{k+1}$ = $y_i$ + $\frac{h}{2}[f(t_i,y_i) + f(t_{i+1},y_{i+1}^{k})]$

for $k\geq 1$ and $y_{i+1}^{0}$ = $y_i$

I applied fix point iteration which is

$x^{k+1}$ = $F(x^{k})$, so

$F(x^{k})$ = $y_i$ + $\frac{h}{2}f(t_i,y_i) + \frac{h}{2}f(t_{i+1},x_{i+1}^{k})$

By Banach fix point theorem, the iteration converges iff F is a contraction. I need help here how to show this.

b) What if the first equation(Instead of Crank -Nicolson) changed to

$y_{i+1}^{k+1}$ = $y_i$ + $\frac{3h}{4}(4-y_i^2) + \frac{h}{4}(4-(y_{i+1}^k)^2)$

for all $k\geq 1$ and $y_{i+1}^{0}$ = $y_i$

c) If the iterative system has a form

$g(x^k)$ = $y_n$ + $\frac{3h}{4}(4-y_n^2) + \frac{h}{4}(4-(x_{n+1}^k)^2)$

for all $k\geq 1$ and $y_{n+1}^{0}$ = $y_n$

How can I perform

$|\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}| $ $<$ 1

so that I can find h.

Comment: "By Banach fix point theorem, the iteration converges iff F is a contraction"?  Where do you get that?

Comment: That is not what Banach's fixed point theorem states. It says that **if** $F$ is a contraction then there is a unique fixed point $x$ such that for any $y$ the iterates $F^n(y)$ converge to $x$. Moreover, the theorem provides estimates on the speed of convergence based on the constant of contraction.

Comment: To really hammer the point, notice that being a contraction is a property that depends on the specific metric used. It's easy to find maps $f$ such that $f$ is a contraction in a metric $d_0$, but fails to be in some other metric $d_1$ (even if we disregard really obvious examples like the discrete metric). On the oher hand, being a fixed point is a property that does not depend on metric at all -- it depends only on how $f$ acts on the space as a **set**.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri Now I understand. Let's say in this specific metric, is it possible to show that F is a contraction?

Comment: @RobertIsrael I know the criteria for a function to be a Banach space and I assumed that all the criteria are fulfilled and the only thing it remains is to show that the contraction property. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I must say I am not too familiar with Crank-Nicolson or numerical methods so I'm not exactly sure about what's going on. Can you clarify what $F$ and metric (usual euclidian distance?) are being asked about?

Comment: @Fimpellizieri Actually the point is to calculate the partial derivative of the iterative system. I put it above in short  in c (in the equation )

Comment: @Tigist "for a function to be a Banach space" makes no sense at all.